# Convert binary to signed int/decimal

Tags: c#, hex, signed-integer

I am trying to convert hex data to signed int/decimal and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I need `FE` to turn into `-2`.

I'm using `Convert.ToInt32(fields[10], 16)` but am getting `254` instead of `-2`.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to turn `FE` into `-2` instead of `254` and how do you know that you need to get `-2` instead of `254`?

Comment: The guy I'm working with wants to see a signed value, not sure why but that's what was requested. It's possible though. This link does it in JavaScript.

http://www.free-test-online.com/binary/signed_converter.html

Comment: That is not a signed int decimal - it's a signed byte if you want to read it that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int` is 32 bits wide, so 0xFE is REALLY being interpreted as 0x000000FE for the purposes of `Convert.ToInt32(string, int)`, which is equal to 254 in the space of `int`.

Since you're wanting to work with a signed byte range of values , use `Convert.ToSByte(string, int)` instead (`byte` is unsigned by default, so you need the `sbyte` type instead).

`Convert.ToSByte("FE",16)`

Answer (score 2):

Interpret the value as a signed byte:

```
sbyte value = Convert.ToSByte("FE", 16); //-2
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the bounds of `Int32` are -2 147 483 648 to 2 147 483 647. So `FE` matches 254.

In case you want to do a wrap around over 128, the most elegant solution is proably to **use a signed byte** (`sbyte`):

```
csharp> Convert.ToSByte("FE",16);   
-2
```